# Delete "Other Contact" using Python with Google People API

Tags: google-api, google-api-python-client, google-contacts-api, google-people-api

I used Google People API `v1.otherContacts.copyOtherContactToMyContactsGroup` ([reference](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/otherContacts/copyOtherContactToMyContactsGroup)) to copy a contact from "Other Contacts" to "myContacts" contact group. I now want to delete the original contact from "Other Contacts" using the same API.

REST Resource `v1.otherContacts` ([reference](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest#rest-resource:-v1.othercontacts)) does not list a `DELETE` action.

---

I tried using `v1.people.deleteContact` ([reference](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/deleteContact)) passing the resource name of my "Other Contact":

```
import pickle
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
    creds = pickle.load(token)

people_api = build('people', 'v1', credentials=creds)
people_service = people_api.people()
response = people_service.deleteContact(resourceName='otherContacts/c1971897568350947161').execute()
```

But I got an error saying:

> TypeError: Parameter "resourceName" value "otherContacts/c1971897568350947161" does not match the pattern "^people/[^/]+$"

Looks like `v1.people.deleteContact` does not work for deleting a contact in "Other Contacts".

---

How can I programmatically delete a contact from "Other Contacts"?

---

**EDIT:** Based on @DaImTo's [suggestion below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66515317/4671117), I tried replacing `otherContacts/` in the resource name with `people/` and invoking the `v1.people.deleteContact` API, but I got an error saying:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/c1971897568350947161:deleteContact?alt=json returned " generic::NOT_FOUND: Contact person resources are not found.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'resourceNames[0]', 'description': 'Resource not found.'}]}]">

Answer (score 0):

I advice consulting the documentation for [people.deleteContact](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/deleteContact)

> Required. The resource name of the contact to delete.

```
DELETE https://people.googleapis.com/v1/{resourceName=people/*}:deleteContact
```

That means it should be `people/c1971897568350947161` assuming that is the id of the user you want to delete `c1971897568350947161`.

Comment: I just tried and this does not work. I cannot just replace `otherContacts/` in the resource name with `people/` and invoke `v1.people.deleteContact`. I got the error: "googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/c1971897568350947161:deleteContact?alt=json returned "<eye3 title='NOT_FOUND'/> generic::NOT_FOUND: Contact person resources are not found.". Details: "[{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest', 'fieldViolations': [{'field': 'resourceNames[0]', 'description': 'Resource not found.'}]}]">".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Other Contacts are read only, according to this announcement from Google: https://developers.google.com/contacts/v3/announcement

> The new People API has the same functionality as the legacy Contacts
> API for all features, with the following exceptions for “Other
> Contacts”:
>
> Administrators have read-only permissions for “Other Contacts” through
> the new scope. As sending mutate/write signals back to “Other
> Contacts” is not supported, your users will have to add the Other
> Contact as a My Contact if they wish to update its data fields.